Derivative of the product of a scalar function and a vector valued function
According to Berkeley Physics Course, Volume 1 Mechanics,
The time derivative of a vector valued function can be derived from the formula:
$$
\mathbf{r}(t) = r(t)\mathbf{\hat{r}}(t)
$$
where the scalar $r(t)$ is the length of the vector and $\mathbf{\hat{r}}(t)$ is a vector of unit length in the direction of $\mathbf{r}$. The derivative of $\mathbf{r}(t)$ is defined as:
$$
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\frac{d\mathbf{r}}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}[r(t)\mathbf{\hat{r}}(t)] = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\frac{r(t+\Delta t)\mathbf{\hat{r}}(t+\Delta t) - r(t)\mathbf{\hat{r}}(t)}{\Delta t}
\end{equation}
$$
Now we use the Taylor series expansion for each of the factors $r(t+\Delta t)$ and $\mathbf{\hat{r}}(t+\Delta t) $
and we only retain the first two terms in the series expansions of $r(t+\Delta t)$ and $\mathbf{\hat{r}}(t+\Delta t)$. The general Taylor expansion series is:
$$
\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
f(x) = f(x_{0}) + (x-x_0)\left[ \frac{df(x)}{dx}\right]_{x=x_0} + \frac{1}{2}(x-x_{0})^{2} \left[ \frac {d^{2}f(x)}{dx^{2}} \right]_{x=x_0} + \cdots
\end{equation}
$$
After substituting the first two terms of the Taylor expansion series(2) into the numerator of equation $(1)$, we obtain
$$
\begin{equation}
\tag{3}
\left[r(t)+\frac{dr}{dt} \Delta t\right] \left[\mathbf{\hat{r}}(t) + \frac {d\mathbf{\hat{r}}}{dt} \Delta t\right] - r(t)\mathbf{\hat{r}}(t) = \Delta t \left(\frac{dr}{dt}\mathbf{{\hat{r}}} + r\frac{d\mathbf{\hat{r}}}{dt} \right) + (\Delta t)^{2}\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\frac{d\mathbf{\hat{r}}}{dt}\right)
\end{equation}
$$
Substituting $(3)$ in $(1)$, we obtain:
$$
\begin{equation}
\tag{4}
\frac{d\mathbf{r}}{dt} = \frac{dr}{dt}\mathbf{\hat{r}} + r\frac{d\mathbf{\hat{r}}}{dt}
\end{equation}
$$
Equation $(4)$ is the general formula for the derivative of the product of a scalar function and a vector valued function.
My question is that why do we prove this formula as an estimated value? Why can't we directly use the product rule for differentiation here?

Oh, you are confusing pedagogy with the state of affairs. The book is trying to find a simple presentation that the students reading from the book can hope to understand, assuming barest understanding of calculus. If you are already familiar with vector calculus enough that you know that product rule works for the vector calculus case just as it does the single variable case, then you can skip all these presentation and go straight to the straightforward definition.

Using a Taylor expansion (and that too a Taylor series) is silly. Just use a product rule (which can be proved at several levels of generality).

The author's point here is that one can treat a vector function like a scalar function when it comes to differentiation. This may be obvious but the book is meant for students with a limited experience with physics, and they could find themselves asking whether or not they can differentiate vector functions. Generally speaking, in introductory physics courses all the vector functions are just constant vectors, and therefore $d\vec{v}/dt=0$, so it's not unlikely that an inexperienced student may not think about differentiating $\vec{r}$ (crucial when written in non cartesian coordinate systems).
